# Run SFML tcp Network program on multiple computers

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, network-programming, sfml

I'm planning to make a TCP-networking 2 player game by SFML, so I already watched this Youtube video. -> [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P2oXfz87Aqs). After that video, I actually made that program, and It works well on my laptop. but when I run this on multiple computers, It doesn't. on that video, he says I can run this on another computer If I set IP address::getLocalAdress to ipAdress::getPublicAdress. I tried, but It was just same.
is there anyone who'll check my code??

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
sf::IpAddress ip = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
sf::TcpSocket socket;
char connectionType;

std::cout << "Enter (s) for sever, Enter (c) for client" << std::endl;
cin >> connectionType;

if (connectionType == 's') { 
    sf::TcpListener listener;
    listener.listen(2000);
    listener.accept(socket);
}
else
    socket.connect(ip, 2000);

sf::RectangleShape rect1, rect2;
rect1.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));
rect2.setSize(sf::Vector2f(20, 20));

rect1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
rect2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

sf::RenderWindow app(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"SFML_ProjectBase", sf::Style::Resize);
sf::Vector2f prevPosition, p2Position;

socket.setBlocking(false);

bool update = false;

while (app.isOpen()) {
    sf::Event e;
    while (app.pollEvent(e)) {
        if (e.type == sf::Event::Closed || (e.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased && e.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)) {
            app.close();
        }
        else if (e.type == sf::Event::GainedFocus) {
            update = true;
        }
        else if (e.type == sf::Event::LostFocus) {
            update = false;
        }
    }
    prevPosition = rect1.getPosition();

    if (update) {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)) 
            rect1.move(0.2f, 0.0f);
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)) 
            rect1.move(-0.2f, 0.0f);
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)) 
            rect1.move(0.0f, -0.2);
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)) 
            rect1.move(0.0f, 0.2f);
    }

    sf::Packet packet;

    if (prevPosition != rect1.getPosition()) {
        packet << rect1.getPosition().x << rect1.getPosition().y;
        socket.send(packet);
    }
    socket.receive(packet);
    if (packet >> p2Position.x >> p2Position.y) {
        rect2.setPosition(p2Position);
    }
    app.draw(rect1); 
    app.draw(rect2);

    app.display();
    app.clear();
}
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should include what the specific problem is and what you where expecting. Just dumping a whole bunch of code and saying "Why is this not working?" is not a proper question for SO. Have you tried to pin down where your code is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is simply the fact that you're setting the wrong target IP in `socket.connect(ip, 2000);`.

- If you're using `sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress()`, you'll get the IP of the current machine the program is running on.
- If you're using `sf::IpAddress::getPublicAddress()`, you'll get the IP your LAN is exposed to the internet (which is typically your router's WAN IP). For this to work it would need proper port forwarding, but might also be blocked for clients connecting from the LAN side (security feature to prevent local malware from faking internet domains).

As a solution, set `ip` to the IP address of the machine running the server. It should connect then.